# Automatically upcase column and table names in activerecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

I work on a rails application which runs in a few different institutions. It has to interface with a legacy database at each one. All these databases were Oracle and all the column names and table names were in lower case.

One of the institutions has moved their DB to a MS SQL database. The structures are all the same, I've connected the app to it and it looks like it will all work fine, except with one problem.

On the MS SQL db, all the table names and column names are now in uppercase.

Is there a way of making active record automatically translate all the calls to the DB to be uppercase? A method I can override somewhere?

---

So, I think (can't test a lot yet) I've fixed the column name part. I've basically done

```
column_names.each {|c| alias_attribute c.downcase, c}
```

in each of the affected models (although I've stuck this in a module I can include, or not, depending on the adapter.

I'm trying to work out what to do for the table names which I can lump into the same module.

Comment: OK. What's wrong with this question to deserve downvotes, then?

Comment: I think your question is a good one, but it doesn't show any effort on your part to solve the problem. Often people will not feel like helping if it looks like you're just trying to get others to do your work for you. Have you tried looking through the ruby documentation to find out how it works out table names? There are a few obvious keywords to start you off, `table_name` for example.

Comment: Fair enough. Probably didn't go into enough detail about what I've tried in the question. I'd fiddled around with redefining table names around. All the affected models have a superclass which creates the connection to the legacy database so I was hoping I could just redefine the table_name method in there by upclassing the super method but it doesn't work; I think because it just ends up asking my superclass for a table name which, of course, doesn't have one.

Comment: Last time I used MS SQL, the default was that the table/column names weren't case sensitive. Is this not the case in your situation?

Comment: Ah, now that's interesting. It certainly is _acting_ case sensitive. Unfortunately the MS SQL is the bit of this I know very little about and I'm having to deal remotely with the administrators of the DB. I'm wondering if it might be asking them if there's a case sensitivity setting or something.

Comment: I suspect rails is also causing some of the issues. It's defining methods based on the column names, etc. and those methods _are_ case sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. After hours wasted trying to code around the problem I found the configuration option in `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` which does it all for you. Just drop:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter.lowercase_schema_reflection = true
```

in to a file in `config/initializers` and everything works.

D'oh!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than set table names for all your models (which will then affect any deployment to another database) I would suggest an initializer to programmatically change the table names to uppercase based on the adapter. It's a bit of guesswork but something like this ought to get you started:

```
#config/initializers/table_name.rb
module ActiveRecord
  module ModelSchema
    module ClassMethods
      def table_name
        reset_table_name unless defined?(@table_name)
        if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_values["config"][:adapter] == "mssql"    
          @table_name.upcase
        else
          @table_name
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is rather similar to how I've started attacking the problem. I'm starting with column names instead of the table names. I've created a module which aliases all the columns as their lower case counterparts and included that into the models.

Comment: @kevtufc can you share a gist of how you managed to override the column names to lowercase

Comment: @carbonr That's it in the accepted answer I wrote. Just stick that one line somewhere it'll get run on startup. I already had a file in config/initializers where I define a few defaults for talking to the database so I put it in there. It fixes everything.